# Adding to local namespace in Python?

Tags: python, namespaces, class, methods

Is there a way in Python to add to the locals name-space by calling a function without explicitly assigning variables locally?

Something like the following for example (which of course doesn't work, because locals() return a copy of the local name-space) where the print statement would print '1'.

```
def A():
  B(locals())
  print x

def B(d):
  d['x'] = 1
```

Comment: I can only ask: Why!? For the love of the Gods of Programmming WHY!? :-)

Comment: Please use assignment statement for assignment of variables.  That's what it's for.  Please do things the simplest, most obvious way.  Please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python `2.*`, you can disable the normal optimizations performed by the Python compiler regarding local variable access by starting your function with `exec ''`; this will make the function very much slower (I just posted, earlier today, an answer showing how the local-variable optimization can easily speed code up by 3 or 4 times), but it will make your desired hack work. I.e., in Python 2.*:

```
def A():
  exec ''
  B(locals())
  print x

def B(d):
  d['x'] = 1

A()
```

will emit `1`, as you desire.

This hack was disabled in Python `3.*` (where `exec` is just a function, not a statement nor a keyword any more) -- the compiler now performs the local variable optimization unconditionally, so there is no longer any way to work around it and make such hacks work.

Comment: Brilliant, this is completely new to me. I'm going to investigate further. 
However I'm not quite really looking for a hack, esp one that'll degrade performance. Alex, how would you do it if you wanted to not explicitly define a set of variables locally (say have them defined dynamically by a subroutine) but want to access them locally as if they are local variables?

Comment: @Dilan, I wouldn't -- "explicit is better than implicit" (do `import this` at an interactive Python prompt to see the whole text of the Zen of Python). There is no way to make local variables that isn't either explicit, or a hack.

Comment: @Dilan, you're welcome, but remember to accept answers to your questions -- not just verbally, but by using the tickmark-like icon near the answer's count of upvotes. That's fundamental SO etiquette!-)

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty horrible to rely on a hack like `exec ''`. What about communicating like this with the global statement, it seems to work:

```
>>> def outer():
...   global x
...   b()
...   print x
... 
>>> def b():
...   global x
...   x = 2
... 
>>> outer()
2
```

You could create a namespace for your variables instead:

```
class Namespace(object):
    pass

def A():
  names = Namespace()
  B(names)
  print names.x

def B(d):
  d.x = 1
```

Then use `names.x` or `getattr(names, "x")` to access the attributes.