# Adding dynamic class to callers namespace

Tags: python

#### Problem

> Unable to dynamically create classes with local scope within a function but works at the top level.

#### Question

> How to create classes dynamically at the correct namespace scope.

---

I'm trying to dynamically create classes that are added to the callers namespace.

So that I'm able to do the following.

```
import creator
creator.make('SomeClass')
print "SomeClass :", SomeClass
```

This can be made to work when adding dynamic classes at the top level **but** when trying to do the same within a function, so that the created class has only local scope, it doesn't work.

I saw that there is ***[hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549221/1481060)*** which works when placed inside the function but that's going to disappear.

The following code shows the problem obviously there would be more to `creator.py` than that shown.

```
# creator.py    
import inspect

def make(classname):
    t = type(classname, (object,), { })
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    print "WILL make() - callers locals :", frame.f_back.f_locals.keys()
    frame.f_back.f_locals[classname] = t
    print "DID  make() - callers locals :", frame.f_back.f_locals.keys()
    return t
```

---

```
# example.py
import creator

print  "WILL __main__ - locals :", locals().keys()
creator.make('SomeClass')
print  "DID  __main__ - locals :", locals().keys()

print "SomeClass :", SomeClass
print "-" * 80

def closed():
    # This hack helps
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549221/1481060
    # exec ''

    class ClosedClass: pass

    print  "WILL closed() - locals :", locals().keys()
    creator.make('AnotherClass')
    print  "DID  closed() - locals :", locals().keys()

    # NOT EXPECTED
    try: print  AnotherClass
    except NameError, ex: print "OUCH:", ex


closed()
```

Output:

```
WILL __main__ - locals : ['creator', '__builtins__', '__file__', '__package__', '__name__', '__doc__']
WILL make() - callers locals : ['creator', '__builtins__', '__file__', '__package__', '__name__', '__doc__']
DID  make() - callers locals : ['creator', '__builtins__', 'SomeClass', '__file__', '__package__', '__name__', '__doc__']
DID  __main__ - locals : ['creator', '__builtins__', 'SomeClass', '__file__', '__package__', '__name__', '__doc__']
SomeClass : <class 'creator.SomeClass'>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WILL closed() - locals : ['ClosedClass']
WILL make() - callers locals : ['ClosedClass']
DID  make() - callers locals : ['ClosedClass', 'AnotherClass']
DID  closed() - locals : ['ClosedClass', 'AnotherClass']
OUCH: global name 'AnotherClass' is not defined
```

Of course I don't want `OUCH:..`.

Looking at `locals()` within `closed` one would imagine it should work but as mentioned in the hack the Python compiler is optimising the locals and missing the introduction of a new dynamic one.

If I uncomment the `exec ''` line then it works.

I could create theses classes with global scope but I'm trying to keep my namespaces clean.

I could of course do `AnotherClass = creator.make('AnotherClass')` but I'm trying to keep it <kbd>DRY</kbd>.

Is there a way of making it work without the `exec ''` hack ?

Or is it a case of making them global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**. The *only* way to access local variables is via [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) or `vars()` and in both cases the documentation specifically tells that there is no guarantee that modifications to the `dict` return will affect the local variables, hence: there is no way to do this reliably.

If you want modify the locals *statically* then *maybe* you can modify the code object associated with the function to provide more locals, but it may not be possible or it could be really hard to do reliably, and I see no reason for doing this.